# How to separate eyeglass lenses and frames

Tags: image, process, mask, detection, segment

I extracted the glasses from the image using a segmentation model. After that, I want to separate the glasses lenses and frames. If there is a good way, please let me know.

For my image processing flow, I referred to [Glasses detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26418558/glasses-detection).

[image]

origin image

[image]

glasses mask

[image]

masked

[image]

output